# Tensorboard loss plots go back in time (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I have a similar problem to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496479/tensorflow-1-4-1-tensorboard-visualization-plot-goes-back-in-time), only I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend rather then Tensorflow.
I have trained 18 MLP models for time series forecasting with different meta parameters, all created with the same basic architecture. The 3 meta parameters I am scanning are the lookahead that the model uses for prediction, the depth of the model, and whether I am using L2 regularization.

```
    model = Sequential()
    # input_shape should be a 3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps ,input_dim)
    model.add(Flatten())
    # hidden layer sizes should drop gradually from 256 to 2*lookahead
    hidden_layer_sizes = [int(256 - i * (256 - 2 * lookahead) / depth) for i in range(depth)]
    for hidden_layer_size in hidden_layer_sizes:
        if regularization:
            model.add(Dense(hidden_layer_size, kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                        kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.01), activation=activations))
        else:
            model.add(Dense(hidden_layer_size, kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                        activation=activations))
    model.add(Dense(2 * lookahead))
    loss = losses.mean_squared_error
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=self.kwargs["optimizer"], metrics=['mae'])
```

Each model's tensorboard data is saved in a seperate folder through the relevant Keras callback

```
callback_tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir,
                                   histogram_freq=5,
                                   write_graph=False,
                                   write_grads=True,
                                   write_images=False)
```

but for some reason, 3 out of the 18 models have two tensorboard files saved instead of one, and the resulting graphs show this weird phenomena of progressing backwards through time
[image]

Why does this happen? and other then deleting the second tensorboard file, what can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because every time you call `mode.fit()` you reinitialize the internal epoch counter in keras. However you could set it up manually when you compile the model like:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss=tf.losses.mean_squared_error)
init_epoch = 0
```

And then when ypu call fit, you can pass additional argument to keras, which describes current epoch:

```
epoch_count = 200
init_epoch += epoch_count
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                batch_size=256,
                epochs=init_epoch,
                validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                verbose=1,
                initial_epoch=init_epoch-epoch_count,
                )
```